# ¿Cómo agregar un prototipo a Object y que for...in omita esa propiedad?

Tags: javascript, prototipos

Quiero agregar el prototipo `keys` a `Object` en *JavaScript*.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
Object.prototype.keys=function(){return Object.keys(this)}
```

Luego, al crear un objeto nuevo, sin nada dentro, y al iterarlo, me devuelve `keys`, pero eso es un problema.

Quisiera que al iterar cualquier objeto con `for...in`, omita el `keys`. ¿Habrá que cambiar algo más en `Object`? ¿o no hay manera porque el `for...in` está diseñado para no omitirlo nunca?

Código:

```js
Object.prototype.keys=function(){return Object.keys(this)}

var objeto={}
for(var i in objeto)
{
  console.log(i)
}
```

Comment: `if (i !== 'keys')` Pero ya está la función `Object.keys()`

Comment: No está claro lo que preguntas. No veo que sea una forma "incorrecta" de agregar un prototipo a Object. De todas formas, puedes utilizar `getOwnPropertyNames` con un `for..of`: `for(var i of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(objecto)) {`

Comment: tu pregunta es sobre el prototype o sobre el for in?

Comment: haz pensado cambiar tu codigo a Clases?, puedo darte un ejemplo

Comment: En general, añadir funcionalidades a las clases que no son tuyas se considera una mala idea, con la excepción de "shimmering": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITADO**

Si deseas que keys sea una función, puedes encapsular el valor en una función y devolverla, en vez de devolver el valor directamente:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'keys', {
  //enumerable: false, // -> Por defecto es false
  get: function(){ return () => Object.keys(this) }
})

var a = {
  c: ''
}


console.log('Propiedad creada: ', a.keys() )

for(var i in a) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

**RESPUESTA ORIGINAL**

También, a parte de lo comentado en los comentarios, lo que puedes hacer es definir una propiedad [**`que no sea enumerable`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/defineProperty):

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'keys', {
  //enumerable: false, // -> Por defecto es false
  get: function(){ return Object.keys(this) }
})

var a = {
  c: ''
}


console.log('Propiedad creada: ', a.keys)

for(var i in a) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te coloco un ejemplo sin usar `prototype` ahora en las versiones nuevas de javascript puedes programar orientado a objeto, el codigo te quedaria mejor y puedes agregar funcionalidades exacta sin alterar el comportamiento comun de un Objeto

```js
class MiClase{
 constructor() {
  this.var1= 1;
  this.var2= 2;
 }
 keys(){return Object.keys(this)}
} 
var objeto=new MiClase();
for(var i in objeto)
{
 console.log(i + ":" + objeto[i] );
  
}
//si quieres ver todos los metodos de tu clase
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(MiClase.prototype));
```

> Si quieres ver que metodos tienen una clase debes usar la siguiente
>   linea:
>
> ```
> (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(MiClase.prototype)
> ```

Ahora si quieres agregar una funcionalidad de una clase ya existentes puedes hacerlo de dos forma una es obviamente el `prototype` y la segunda es Herencia, la primera la explican otros usuarios en esta pregunta mientra la segunda se haria de esta forma:

```js
  class ClasePadre{
     constructor() {
      this.var1= 1;
      this.var2= 2;
     }
  }
  class ClaseHijo extends ClasePadre{
    constructor () {
      super();
    }
    keys(){return Object.keys(this)}
  
  }  
    
    var objeto=new ClaseHijo();
    for(var i in objeto)
    {
     console.log(i)
    }
    console.log(objeto.keys());
```